# Should I use steps per execution if I can achieve an ideal batch size with a TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am working with a TPU and have managed to achieve an ideal batch size of `128 * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync`. I am wondering whether it is still beneficial to include the `steps_per_execution` argument in the `.compile()` method of my model.

From my understanding, `steps_per_execution` is used to increase the number of steps executed per call to `tf.function`, which can help reduce the overhead of multiple calls to the TPU, especially when the batch size can't be pushed to very high values to optimize TPU performance. However, since I have already achieved an ideal batch size, is there any advantage in using `steps_per_execution`?

Usually, I set `steps_per_execution` to 32 if I can't achieve an ideal batch size, i.e. due to HBM limitations.

Any insights or suggestions on when to use the steps per execution argument, and if so, how to determine an appropriate value for it?